# Java enum formatting in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, enums

I've been tweaking my syntax colouring options in eclipse. Is there a way to format the appearance of enum values? All I found was the enum values seem to use the same formatting as static final fields, but I'd like them to be different if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the appearance of enum values. You will find the settings here:
Right-Click on your code -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring -> Java -> Static final fields

But keep in mind that this will not only effect the enum values.

Comment: That setting seems to only change the format of the name of the enum class, but not the actual values of the enum. E.g. ![here](https://s27.postimg.org/ocbue8xfn/enum.png) is what happens when I make enums red - the enum values are still blue but the enum name is red.

Comment: Aha, I guess I replied to your answer before your edit. I've seen that enums use static final field formatting, but what just hoping there was a way to format them separately - apparently not. Thanks anyway!